# How to use Mathematica to evaluate the limit of Exponential Functions?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How I can calculate a limit using l'Hopital's Rule,
limit of (e^-2x +3x)^1/x , as x approaches infinity.

How can I do it in Mathematica?

Comment: Did you look in the documentation to the `Limit` command? The second example there is helpful.

Comment: Try to write correct syntax. It is not clear what "(e^-2x +3x)^1/x" means. Exponentiation is written by: `Exp[...]` . And Hopital's Rule needs 2 function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

What you wrote is

```
(E^-2 x + 3 x)/x // Simplify

(* 3 + 1/E^2 *)
```

Presumably you meant to write

```
expr = (E^(-2 x) + 3 x)/x;
```

First, check that l'Hopital's rule is applicable

```
Limit[#, x -> Infinity] & /@ {Numerator[expr], Denominator[expr]}

(* {∞, ∞} *)
```

The derivatives are

```
D[{Numerator[expr], Denominator[expr]}, x]

(* {3 - 2 E^(-2 x), 1} *)
```

The limits of the derivatives are

```
Limit[%, x -> Infinity]

(* {3, 1} *)
```

The ratio of the limits is the limit of `expr`

```
Divide @@ %

(* 3 *)
```

Verifying,

```
Limit[expr, x -> Infinity]

(* 3 *)
```

Clear["Global`*"]

**EDIT:** As `bill s` pointed out in a comment, I misinterpreted your expression. A slightly modified approach is needed.

```
expr2 = (E^(-2 x) + 3 x)^(1/x);
```

To use l'Hopital's rule we must work with the `Log`

```
expr3 = Log[expr2] // PowerExpand

(* Log[E^(-2 x) + 3 x]/x *)
```

Then following the same procedure

```
Limit[#, x -> Infinity] & /@ {Numerator[expr3], Denominator[expr3]}

(* {∞, ∞} *)

D[{Numerator[expr3], Denominator[expr3]}, x]

(* {(3 - 2 E^(-2 x))/(E^(-2 x) + 3 x), 1} *)

Limit[%, x -> Infinity]

(* {0, 1} *)

Divide @@ %

(* 0 *)
```

Since we were working with the `Log`, the limit of `expr2` is

```
E^%

(* 1 *)
```

Verifying,

```
Limit[expr2, x -> Infinity]

(* 1 *)
```

Comment: My guess would have been: Limit[(E^(-2 x) + 3 x)^(1/x), x -> Infinity]  which has a limit of 1.

Comment: @bills - Thanks, corrected.

Comment: @bills Now ma.stackexchange goes to the next level---not only providing, but also guessing the questions :)

Comment: @yarchik Is that a surprise? I thought most of us are AI bots anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation....